# why python command does not invoke python interpreter in powershell though py is working

Tags: python, powershell, sublimetext3

I am using windows 10 operating system. I had downloaded and installed [Ananconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) python 3.6 version for windows 64 bit.

I had added Anaconda to windows path manually. The current path is as below.

I have also added the PYTHONPATH variable.
[image]

The command py launches the python interpreter as below.
[image]

But the command python fails with below error.

[image]

How do I fix the issue. I am trying to run a simple hello World on sublime text but the same is failing with below error.

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "D:\Python_Test\testprinting.py"]
[dir: D:\Python_Test]
```

Comment: The python exe file is available in the ProgramData\Anaconda3 path. I am able to invoke the interpreter from the path with ./python.

Comment: So it's accessible at `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe`?  Did you restart your powershell session after modifying the PATH?

Comment: Yes it is accessible at the path where it is installed but not from other directories. Because of which the python build is failing in sublime text.

Comment: Trivially you could modify the `sublime-build` to run `py` instead of `python`, but it's better to fix the underlying problem. It won't work from Sublime as-is unless executing `python` works from a command prompt. Did you try restarting the powershell session as @TheIncorrigible1 mentioned? If that works, restarting Sublime will work as well (so it can pick up the new path).

Comment: I did restart the power-shell session, as well as my system but python interpreter is not launching in other directories other than the one it is installed in.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out the exact reason why python was not being recognized as a command even thought the path C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\ was added to the path variable with and without quotes "". I reinstalled the Anaconda3 package and then manually added the path. This time python command invokes the interpreter and its working fine in sublime text.